# How to invite visitors friends to my website using Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I used to use FBML to let people invite theirfriends using Facebook to my site.
But it's not working anymore because it seems that Facebook is deprecating FBML.

Is it still possible to have a multi selection of users and invite them/post to their wall using Facebook's Javascript SDK?

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give more detail?  What was FBML that allowed you to post/invite?

Answer (score 1):

This [jQuery plugin](http://thechangelog.com/post/2957861449/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-a-jquery) uses the graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to invite users to your Site/Application it is supporting multiple users selection and generates "request" (this doesn't posting anything to wall of invited users but send 'em notification)

Comment: According to the linked article, "Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and Android apps." This may be a recent change, but it seems to prevent using this dialog for inviting users to external websites.